# Unique rows in Listview (Userform) VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a table in excel and I want to have the records displayed in a userform using the listview control. The challange I'm facing is that I only want 5 columns to be displayed and only unique rows.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
Private Sub LoadListView()

Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim rngData, rngCell As Range
Dim LstItem As ListItem
Dim RowCount, ColCount, i, j As Long
Dim CountryCol, ShippingWay, SortCode, FirstException, LastException, Performance_OK_NOK, Container, 
CountSimilar, a As Integer

Set wksSource = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set rngData = wksSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Me.ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="RowNr", Width:=70

For Each rngCell In rngData.Rows(1).Cells
If rngCell = "service_def_code" Or rngCell = "package_sort" Or rngCell = "ship_to_country_id" Or 
    rngCell = "first_tracking_exception_message" _
    Or rngCell = "last_tracking_exception_message" Then
       Me.ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=rngCell.Value, Width:=80

End If

Next rngCell

RowCount = rngData.Rows.Count
ColCount = rngData.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To ColCount
If wksSource.Cells(1, i) = "ship_to_country_id" Then
   CountryCol = i
ElseIf wksSource.Cells(1, i) = "service_def_code" Then
   ShippingWay = i
ElseIf wksSource.Cells(1, i) = "package_sort" Then
   SortCode = i
ElseIf wksSource.Cells(1, i) = "first_tracking_exception_message" Then
   FirstException = i
ElseIf wksSource.Cells(1, i) = "last_tracking_exception_message" Then
   LastException = i
ElseIf wksSource.Cells(1, i) = "performance_result" Then
   Performance_OK_NOK = i

End If

Next i

j = 1

For i = 2 To RowCount
If wksSource.Cells(i, Performance_OK_NOK) = "NOK" then
  Set LstItem = Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=j)
      LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngData(i, CountryCol)
      LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngData(i, ShippingWay)
      LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngData(i, SortCode)
      LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngData(i, FirstException)
      LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngData(i, LastException)
      j = j + 1

end if

next i

end sub
```

So what I want to do is to have only unique rows displayed and the subitems represents a row. I checked and searched for a solution, but couldn't find one which I understand. Can someone please help?

Comment: You could copy the records in  a temporary sheet and then you could use  [Range.RemoveDuplicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates). This table could be then the rowsource for the listview. But without any further information on the records you have it will be difficult to help you, at least IMO.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a dictionary. For each row create a key with the values of the five columns. if it is not in the dictionary, add it to the dictionary, add it to the listview.

The below example creates a key from columns a, b. Adapt it so you create your key based on your five columns. below i only get "b2" once even though it appears twice in table(cols a,b)

[image]

```
Public Sub sAddToList()

  'REQUIRES MICROSOFT SCRIPTING RUNTIME LIB, (Add using Tools->References from the VB menu)
  
  Dim d As Dictionary
  Dim rowKey As String
  Dim i As Integer
  
  Set d = New Dictionary

  For i = 1 To 4
    rowKey = CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value) + CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value)
    If Not d.Exists(rowKey) Then
      d.Add rowKey, rowKey
      'add to your list view
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

***IF YOUR EXCEL SUPPORTS the UNIQUE function then there is no need for VBA.***
[image]

Comment: I think you need to remove white spaces from the cell values.

Comment: as you said above, "But without any further information on the records...". I guess you could do that.

Comment: Yes, right :-) We need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)